# Running firebase admin and firestore on google app engine

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am currently running a node js server on Google App Engine, in the server, I am using `firebase-admin` package to interact with firebase. I am following the docs `https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup` and initialise the app like this:

```
import admin from 'firebase-admin';

const NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV;

if (NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  admin.initializeApp();
} else {
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires
  const firebaseAccountCredentials = require('../../credentials.json');
  const serviceAccount = firebaseAccountCredentials as admin.ServiceAccount;
  admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  });
}

export const db = admin.firestore();
```

It works all fine locally, as I am passing the `credentials` however when it is run inside App Engine, I see this error: `details: 'The Cloud Firestore API is not available for Datastore Mode projects.'`.

Do I have to set service accounts to connect to firebase? If so how? Couldn't find the documentation for that.

This is my `app.yaml`

```yaml
runtime: nodejs
env: flex
```

Thanks

Comment: The firebase documentation link that you gave does list info to set up service account. The code presented there looks slightly different then yours

Comment: The error message you see is same as this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58001922/gcp-firestore-api-is-not-available-for-cloud-datastore-projects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message you are getting is pretty self explanatory. What is happening is that you are trying to connect to a Firestore DB in Datastore mode with the Firestore admin SDK, which is not possible.

The reason why this was working in your local environment is likely because you were using an emulator with Firestore properly setup in Native mode, but in the live environment you probably set it up as a Firestore with Datastore mode, in order to fix it you will have to [create another Firestore in Native mode](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#create).

Comment: Yes, I activated the Firestore in Native in GCP , and now everything is working fine. Thanks a lot :)